# Есть ли пакеты в java 7 для группировки и сортировки list<map<String,Object>>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Есть ли стандартные пакеты в java 7 для группировки и сортировки

```
list<map<String,Object>>
```

?

Это набор строк в котором данные лежат По именам столбцов, Представление так сказать таблицы с колонками.

К примеру , обьект содержит отчет, в каждой строке которого содержится 5 сущностей( id1..id5- уникальные идентификаторы сущностей, sum1-sum5 - соответствующие суммы и date1-date5 - даты).

требуется отсортировать строки с учетом группировки по всем id, группы отсортировать по датам, внутри группы - по суммам.

Comment: В каком смысле групировать?
какой рещультат хочется получить?

Comment: На выходе переставить строчки местами без изменения данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет стандартной сортировки листа, состоящего из мап. Для этого интерфейс мап должен быть унаследован от интерфейса Comparable, но это два разных понятия.

Можно воспользоваться методом

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Но даже в этом случае придётся писать свой компаратор для мап.

Что же касается сортировки содержимого мап - можно воспользоваться классом TreeMap. Без компаратора данные будут отсортированы в натуральном порядке, с компаратором - как напишете, так и отсортирует.

Comment: Требуется отсортировать list, а map использовать только как набор значений. Сортировать лист, как я понимаю прийдется с учетом 5 групп, для которых нужно еще отыскать агрегатные значения отдельных ключей(типа min(),max() или sum()) и всё это учесть в скопе при сортировке... Перед тем как кодить, я хочу понять , есть стандартные предложения на рынке или нет;(

Comment: А есть класические пакеты для группировки/сортировки данных? Я слышал, что можно чуть ли селекты писать по наборам данных!

Comment: Arrays и Collections сортируют примитивные типы в естественном порядке, а объекты - либо по интерфейсу объектов Comparable, либо через отдельный Comparator.  В Java8 есть Stream<T>, с которым это выглядит короче и, полагаю, "селектами" Вам назвали именно это.